# jquery scroll doesn't work in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm going to use jquery scroll in some part of my webiste. the code that i have used is below of course i wrapped this code with $(document).ready():

```
var div = $('#wrap'),
    wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),
    wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
    listHeight = div.find('ul').outerHeight();

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY,
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});
```

and my html and css is:

```
<div id="wrap">
                <ul>

            <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li> 
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                    <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></h3></li>
                        <li><h3><a href="#">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a>just comedown but it doesn't go up</h3></li>


                  </ul>
                </div>
```

the code work fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/6/) but unfortunately when im using it in my website, it just goes down but doesn't go up while mouse moves.
[this is my website link](http://2day.hisend.ir/)==>in my website i wrap the scroll section with 1px red border!!
[and this is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/6/)

Comment: BTW: And how do users without a mouse (e.g. all users with a touch screen device) reach the content?

Comment: it doesn't important just scrolling down and up is enough for my user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also doesn't work in Fiddle, you think it works but if you put your `div` 300px down (for example), it behaves the same as on your site [(see your fiddle modified and it doesn't work)](http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/301/).

When `onmousemove` triggers, `e` has the value of the mouse relative to the document. You need this value relative to your `div`.

```
var div = $('#wrap'),
    wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),
    wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
    listHeight = div.find('ul').outerHeight();

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY-$(this).position().top, //<== the position of the cursor relative to the div, not the document
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/300/)

Comment: im remove postion:abosulte and top of my website css but the problem doesn't solve

Comment: @Hussein change this `var cPointY = e.pageY-e.posY` on your code to this `var cPointY = e.pageY-posY`.

Comment: i just changed but as you see the problem is still resist

Comment: mmmm, I've updated my answer, try this : `var cPointY = e.pageY-$(this).position().top`.

Comment: you are excellent and very intelligence i love you tooo muchhhhhhhh

Comment: Glad it worked. Did you understand the error? We put on `posY` the offset of the `div` relative to the top of the document, but as we did it on the page loading, this offset changed when we scrolled down the page. Using `$(this).position().top` we get this offset at the moment of do the proccess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48808/discussion-between-hussein-and-ojovirtual)